# How can I select an <option> with a space in it by typing the name of the option including the space?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, browser

I am entering address information on a web site. I live in a state with a space in the name: New York. I focus the `<select>` and start typing "New" and then as soon as I hit the spacebar the entire `<select>` opens up and my continued typing of "York" now ends up selecting "Wyoming" for me. Is there any way around this besides stopping after the `<select>` opens and hitting the arrows to move down to the correct option?

If I were selecting an option which doesn't contain a space I would simply type enough characters to match the option unambiguously. The fact that the spacebar serves as both a character which might appear in a given option and a shortcut to open the entire `<select>` breaks this pattern.

Here's a simple example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGrYBG

I'm using Chrome on Mac OS X but I would be curious if a solution exists on any platform.

Comment: On any platform? On Windows spacebar doesn't make the combo box open (Alt+up/down arrow does), so I can type "New York" just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just press "n" repeatedly until "New York" pops up.  Then press enter.  Or tab to get to the next field.

Comment: Perfect. This is so simple yet somehow I never knew about it before. Thanks!

Comment: I just tried adding an option "nnnnn" and this technique still cycles through all options beginning with "n" rather than selecting the matching one, for what it's worth.